# C++ Characters not being handled properly

Tags: c++

I have a basic encryption program that I have written, it takes input from the user from their encrypted text, usually in the form of Unicode characters. But when I do this:

```
cout << "Your decrypted string is : " << decryptstring(text, key) << endl;
```

It gives me the wrong answer and gets the character codes wrong completely such as `è` will be `-118`.

However when i do:

```
cout << "Your decrypted string is : " << decryptstring("è", key) << endl;
```

It works seamlessly!

How do I fix this? If you need to see my other code just ask. Thanks

I get text from `getline(cin, text);`

decryptstring function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
string decryptstring(string text, string key)
{
    //Declare variables
    int i = 1;
    int result;
    int tmp;
    int tmp2;


    vector < char > arr;



    //Start decryption
    while(i <= text.length())
    {
        /*
        Get letter from the string and get letter from key
        and use Vigenere cipher to decrypt the data.
        */
        tmp  = text[i - 1];

        tmp2 = key[i - 1];
        cout << tmp << endl;
        //Get encrypted value
        result = tmp - tmp2;
        //Change it into readable stuff
        arr.push_back(result);

        //Increment i
        i++;
    }

    string str(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    return str;
}
```

Comment: `text` is in the wrong encoding.

Comment: seriously, we'll need a mindreader to answer this. You give none of your code, you don't even define the type of `text`... This is totally impossible to answer. I recommend reading the help section about how to ask answerable questions.

Comment: @tkausl How can i fix that?

Comment: `wcout` for a start. Also `L"è"` for using wide character strings

Comment: @MarcusMüller text is a string type, it is given a value by `getline(cin, text);`

Comment: @aidan the rules are simple: when describing a problem with your code, your question **must** include your code (in this case, the implementation of `decryptstring`, which I kind of feel is obvious, you don't go to your car mechanic and complain about strange noise in your car, and don't bring your car), and a minimal, verifiable (read: compilable) example of how to trigger the misbehaviour in the question itself.

Comment: @EdHeal There is nothing wrong with the output when i pass the character in a string... It's only wrong when i use a variable. So i don't thin think the output is wrong

Comment: You are lucky with that  character. It is in the ASCII range methinks

Comment: You might want to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` and `std::wcin` instead of `std::cin`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you. Updated the code.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad When i used std::wstring i got a compiler error saying i cant't use it with cin so what do i do?

Comment: @aidan I updated my comment. Use `std::wcin` instead of `std::cin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use wide characters for unicode.

So have `decryptstring` thus:

```
std::wstring decryptstring(const std::wstring& text, const std::wstring& key) {
   // Do stuff
   return text;
}
```

Then

```
std::wcout << L"Your decrypted string is : " << decryptstring(text, key) < std::endl;
std::wcout << L"Your decrypted string is : " << decryptstring(L"è", key) << std::endl;
```

Where

```
std::wstring text; // is declared before use
```

Comment: What about `std::wcin` instead of `std::cin`?

Comment: Yes. Of course. I answered this before the code was published